# Load Mission Fails in Android using DJI 4.5.1

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am using the latest version of DJI which is 4.5.1 and using WaypointMissionOperator for loading the mission, still I am getting the same error while trying to load mission. Can anyone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information would be helpful.  A little code snippet would help or some additional detail like how many points, etc?

Can you describe your data flow, aka, what calls and in what order?  Is the mission failing to load and is there any detail in the error return?

final DJIError djiError = missionOperator.loadMission(mission);

```
                    if (djiError != null) {
                        Log.d("TEST", djiError.getDescription()));
                    }
```